# Install a network printer with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, printing, system

I need to connect a lot of computers to a network printer, and I would like to send a simple batch file that do that instead of explain to each one how to use the windows wizard.

I searched on microsoft documentation and so far I can install a printer by using the printui.dll library, but only if I'm going through another computer, example:
I installed the printer through the wizard on a computer called PC1, and I set it in sharing mode, the name of the printer is PRINTER1
I can now run the command:

```
rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /in /n\\PC1\PRINTER1
```

The problem is that in a configuration like that, if I delete the printer on PC1, every other computer will lose it too, and I can't figure out how to install the printer with his IP.

I would like something like that:

```
rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /in /n 216.1.32.75 /m  "Lexmark W812 (MS)" /b MY_PRINTER
```

When 216.1.32.75 is the printer ip, Lexmark W812(MS) is the driver needed and MY_PRINTER is the local alias of the printer.

All the computers are based on Windows 8.